# Downloads gradually slow down in speed

Tags: windows-7, download, internet-connection, file-download

I've been trying to download a graphics driver for my new Windows 7 PC. I downloaded it, my speed started out at 2 MB/s, and it downloaded. Then after a few seconds, it stopped downloading and the speed kept going down, until it reached 0, at which point the download stopped and gave me a connection error. I thought, "Maybe it's just bad servers", so I downloaded some test files off the internet (and some real programs too.) What I found is that I got the same exact issue. If anyone can help, that'd be great. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your network adapter?

Comment: My router is a TP-Link Archer C7 and I'm also using a TP-link Range Extender

Comment: I meant the network adapter inside the computer.

Comment: Oh, I have a USB network adapter (a D-Link DWA-125 adapter), without that my internet doesn't work, I assume that's what you meant, but if the previous information helps,that's there too
Also I know you didn't ask for this but my network card is a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

Comment: Thank you. I can't find any updates to the DLink later than 2016. If you can find an external (usb) network adapter you could verify if the problem is with it.

Comment: No, it isn't. I've swapped it out for a different one (same model and stuff), and the problem still persisted.

Comment: OK, next stop : Are you connecting directly to the router by Ethernet cable?

Comment: No, I'm using wireless

Comment: Does the problem happen if you connect by Ethernet cable?

Comment: Yes, yes it does

Comment: So this seems like a problem with the computer. (1) While connecting via Ethernet, run Network and Sharing Center > Troubleshoot problems, and do both the "Network Adapter" and "Internet Connections" sections. (2) Follow the article about [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

Comment: Are you downloading to C:? If so, how much free space do you have on your C: drive, and how much total space has that drive?

Answer (score -1):

Try to download from a different machine. Smartphone. Your friend's laptop. With both wireless and ethernet.

1. If the problem persists in all media and both forms you might want to
   have a chat with your ISP or replace your home infrastructure.
   (Router,modem etc)
2. If the problem only manifests in your computer launch from a liveboot
   usb. Like [Hiren's boot](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and see if you can replicate the problem wired and wireless.
   If with a liveboot you still have this issue I would claim your motherboard might have some issues.
   But before you jump into the deep end try some friendly console commands to reset your NIC settings.
3. > Start : type "cmd", wait. Right click on "cmd.exe" and choose "Run as admin" "Yes" on the warning.
4. > On that fancy new console that popped on screen type "netsh gsock reset" and press enter wait for the command to register and then
   >   move on to "netsh int tcp reset"
5. > Again wait for the command to do it's thing and move on to the next "ipconfig -flushdns" followed by "ipconfig -release" ( on this one
   >   you'll loose your network settings and it might get stuck, never
   >   fear press ctrl + c to stop him and give you back the writting
   >   control) finally type "ipconfig -renew" this will renew your
   >   settings.
   >   *Source : Experience, working in IT, reading a bunch*